# How to create line breaks in console.log() in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to get new lines in *console.log* when printing multiple objects?

Suppose we have `console.log(a, b, c)` where `a`, `b`, and `c` are objects. Is there a way to get a line break between the objects?

I tried `console.log(a, '\n', b, '\n', c)`, but that does not work in Node.js.

Comment: console.log(a, '\n', b, '\n', c);

Comment: `console.log(a); console.log(b); console.log(c)` works as well

Comment: Use this- console.log('a','\n','b','\n','c');
    Put a, b and c inside single quotes.

Comment: What OS and which version of node do you use (node --version)?

Comment: @OriDrori — There's no mention of node in the question. This might be about a browser-based implementation of console.log.

Comment: @Quentin - Not in this one, but in the other question he's open and was closed as duplicate by you :) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660591/in-node-create-multi-line-breaks-in-console-log.

Comment: the problem is with node, hence I opened a second question as it's not a duplicate of this one

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have no idea why this works in Node.js, but the following seems to do the trick:

```
console.log('', a, '\n', b, '\n', c)
```

Comment: Because console.log has two variations. When you use string as first arg, it considers the string as format string with other arguments as substitutions (so its one giant string ultimately). If you use any other type as first argument, it just dumps the string representations of all the arguments as is.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation; if it was an answer I'd give it a bounty!  Also, /rude to the Node devs for such a terribly inconsistent `console.log` design!

Comment: What is *"theBlueFish"*? A user here? A website? [The text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluefish_(software))? Something else?

Answer (score 56):

Add `\n` (newline) between them:

```js
console.log({ a: 1 }, '\n', { b: 3 }, '\n', { c: 3 })
```

Comment: it just print the " '\n' " in the console too!

Answer (score 17):

Without adding white space at the start of a new line:

`console.log("one\ntwo");`

Output:

`one`
`two`

This will add white space at the start of a new line:

`console.log("one", "\n", "two");`

Output:

`one`
`two`

Answer (score 11):

You can use a template literal:

```
console.log(`a is line 1
b is line 2
c is line 3`)
```

To activate a template literal, you need to click on the character to the left of number 1 (on my keyboard - Microsoft Wired 600).

*Do not confuse*: The `'` symbol is the same as <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>@</kbd> on my keyboard with `` ` ``.

`'` and `"` will create strings and `` ` `` will create template literals.

Comment: this seems to be the best solution. Why is this not the top answer?

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is creating your own logger along with the original logger from JavaScript.

```js
var originalLogger = console.log;
console.log = function() {
  for (var o of arguments) originalLogger(o);
}

console.log({ a: 1 }, { b: 3 }, { c: 3 })
```

If you want to avoid any clash with the original logger from JavaScript:

```js
console.ownlog = function() {
  for (var o of arguments) console.log(o);
}

console.ownlog({ a: 1 }, { b: 3 }, { c: 3 })
```

Comment: This is a similar approach I would take as well, although, perhaps it was downvoted because it kind of mangles console.log. It may be better to offer an alternative name for the function instead of overwriting console.log.

Comment: @TravisJ yes, probably.

Answer (score 3):

Using one call avoids code duplication -> no multiple calls

Using a template literal works, but is sensitive to formatting -> no template literal

I guess browsers pick their own way to delimit arguments, and there is no way to specify the delimiter. It seems to be a space. -> no specify '\n' as delimiter

After considering these solutions, we arrive at what @Vasan has pointed out in a comment - `console` has powerful printf-style formatting capabilities.

```js
const s1 = "foo";
const s2 = "bar";

const a = { a: 1 };
const b = { b: 2 };

console.info("Remove space delimiter");
console.log("%s%s", s1, s2);

console.info("Separate with newline");
console.log("%s\n%s", s1, s2);

// Interactive object and label
// See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log#logging_objects
console.info("Interactive object and label");
console.log(
  "%s\n%o",
  "`a` object",
  a,
);

// Object snapshot and label
// See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log#logging_objects
console.info("Object snapshot and label");
console.log(
  "%s\n%o",
  "`a` object is",
  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)),
);

console.info("Multiple objects *");
console.log("%o\n%o", a, b);
```

* Awkwardly, in Firefox, it seems that objects that are not the first nor last replacement argument have spaces on both sides no matter what. This does not seem to be the case in Chrome.

See [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) and particularly [console string substitutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#using_string_substitutions).

###### Aside

console output can even be styled using some CSS properties.

See https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in for an example of this.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#styling_console_output

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be a simple:

```
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do `console.log({ a, b, c });`

Example:

```js
var a = 'var a';
var b = 'var b';
var c = 'var c';

console.log({ a, b, c });
```

This will add an expandable area in the console:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

New line character:

```
console.log("\n");
```

You can try this:

```
console.log(a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c);
```

Comment: **This has already been mentioned in some other answers.** When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `\n` inside the `console.log` like this:

```
console.log('one','\n','two');
```

Answer (score 1):

With backticks, you can simply add variables and "\n":

```js
const a = {k1: 'key1', k2: 2};
const b = "string";
const c = 123;
console.log(`${JSON.stringify(a)}\n${b}\n${c}`);
```

will log:

```
{"k1":"key1","k2":2}
string
123
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 const a = {k1: 'key1', k2: 2};
 const b = "string";
 const c = 123;
 console.log(`${JSON.stringify(a)}
 ${b}
 ${c}`);
```

`` takes multiline input and produce output with multilines.