# How to create console.log?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I want to finish my JavaScript code professionally.

I want to do a `console.log` like a picture so... I go to https://www.text-image.com/ and convert my picture into ASCII. This is my picture in ASCII text for example...

`````
  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``  ``   ```-/+osyhhhhhhyso+/-```   ``  ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  
``   ``  ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``  ./shmdys+//:..--..://+shdmhs/.  ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``  ``   ``
  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``./ymhs/-`  ``   ``  ``   ``  `-/sdmy/.``  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  
``   `   ``   `   ``  ``   ``+hmy/````  ``   `   ``   `   ``  ````/ymh+``   ``  ``   `   ``   `   ``
                          -ymy:``                                  ``:ymy-                          
  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``  -hmo.``   `   ``  ``   ``...`   ``  ``   `   ``.omh-  ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  
``   `   ``   `   ``  .ymo.``  ``   ``  `-/++oyhhddhhhs+++:.  ``   ``  ``.omy.  ``   `   ``   `   ``
  ``   ``  ``   ``  `/my.``  `-/:``  .+oo/-++/-..+o.-./+/-:+o+-  ``-+-`  ``.ym/`  ``   ``  ``   ``  
``   ``  ``  ``   ``sN/` ``-sdm/`  :sy-``++.``.  ++  -.``/+.`.+y+` `/dms:`. `+Ns``   ``  ``  ``   ``
  ``   ``  ``   ```hm- .yo/NNs-  /y/`.:oy+:-.-```/+```/`../yo//::so` .smN+oh- :mh```   ``  ``   ``  
``   ``  ``  ``  `hm. `dh`ho++ .y+` ``:o..`-+////sy///+y:-..++``  :y/ /+oh.ym` .mh`  ``  ``  ``   ``
  ``   ``  ``   `yN.`+-M/-sds.:d/``  :s`  `--  ``/+``  +:`  `+/  ``-ho`ods-:M:+.-Ny`   ``  ``   ``  
``   `   ``   ` /M/`ys/Mhmy:`:h-.::::h.``` /``   ++   `.y ````y:-::..oo`:ymyM+oh`/M/ `   ``   `   ``
               `mh`-M++Ny/s`.d-   `.y/:////s/::::ss:::::d////:-y.`   `y/`s/sNo/M:`hm`               
  ``   ``  ``  /M- -Mo-+ym: s+`   ``h```  ./``...+o...``y-  `` o-`   `.d`:dh+-+M: :M/  ``  ``   ``  
``   ``  ``  ``hm :.MhoNd- `m` ``  -s`  ``:- ``  /+  `` o/``  `-+  ``  y/ -hNsyM./ mh``  ``  ``   ``
  ``   ``  ``  Ny`o:yMNo/:`-h``  ``+/ ``  +-````:++:`` `s+  `` `s``  ``/s`-++NNh-s`yN  ``  ``   ``  
``   ``  ``  ``Mo yy.ms/N` :d//////ys////+yyhd. -hs. :dydy+/////h//////sy `m+oN.sh oM``  ``  ``   ``
  ``   ``  `` `Mo`/M/:/Ny``.h``  ``++.oyhdNMMy `.y+```mMMNdhyo``o``  ``+o``sM+/:N+`sM` ``  ``   ``  
``   ``  ``  ``Ny `yN:dN.- `d` ``  -ysMMMMMMMs`  y+  `dMMMMMMM/::  ``  y- -.mm-Nh` yN``  ``  ``   ``
  ``   ``  ``  hm`-.yNNs-m` /o`  ```yNMMMMMMMm```my``.MMMMMMMMho```  `-y `d:oMmh.:`mh  ``  ``   ``  
``   `   ``   `+M-+y-oN++M:``s:``.-:hMMMMMMMMMo `Md `hMMMMMMMMMh/-.```y.`-Mo/Ns-yo-M+`   ``   `   ``
               `my`hm/:-sM:` `s+:-.`mMMMMMMMMMM+-MN`sMMMMMMMMMMy`.--/s: `-My-//mh`hm`               
   `   ``  ``   /M:`sNh:oM+::``o:```MMMMMMMMMMMMdMMdMMMMMMMMMMMm ` .o-`-:/Mo:hNy`/M/   ``  ``   `   
``   ``  ``  ``  ym-.+hNmMd`d+ `/+.-MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM``/+` /d`hMmNd+.-Ny  ``  ``  ``   ``
  ``   ``  ``   ``hd-ss+sdN:+Mo  `/yMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM++-  +Mo-Nds+sy-mh``   ``  ``   ``  
``   ``  ``  ``   .hd-ommyo/.dM/:-`yMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMo`-/:Nm-/oydmo-mh.   ``  ``  ``   ``
  ``   ``  ``   `` `sm/.+dNNdymN/yhhNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMmshy/NmydNNd+./ms` ``   ``  ``   ``  
``   ``  ``  ``   `` /my.`++osydd+/dNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNm/+ddyso++..ym/ ``   ``  ``  ``   ``
  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``.sm+-ohysooooodMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNMMdooooosyhs-oms.``  ``   ``  ``   ``  
``   `   ``   `   ``  ``-ym+.:+syssso+/oMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM+/+osssyy+:-+my-``  ``   `   ``   `   ``
                          -sms::+ooshdmMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNdhsoo+::sms-                          
  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``   `  `+hds+/+oo+dMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMy+oo+/+sdh+`  `   ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  
``   ``  ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  ./ymho/.mMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMy./ohmy/.  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``  ``   ``
  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``  ``-/shNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNhs/-``  ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  
``   ``  ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  ``   ``  .:/+osyyhhhhyyso+/:.  ``   ``  ``   ``  `` 

``  ``  ``   ``
`````

And now I need to get this into a my html code for example this is my code:

```
<html>
    <script>
       console.log("A ANONYMOUS IMAGE FOR EXAMPLE");
    </script>       
</html>
```

I saw a console.log image on website quizlet.com and I want to do it either. I see a `/` and `n` scripts and I don't know what is it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please take the [tour] - Adding more code to your page without obvious benefit does not make it 'professional' (in fact, the opposite is true)

Comment: Professionals don't draw goofy ASCII figures in their code

Comment: Isn't professionality rather about quality of your work?

Comment: If you don't know about escape sequences, then you need to start with the basics.

Answer (score -1):

While subjectively I feel that what you're trying to do is counter to your goals, your Javascript is accurate.

```
console.log('Your art goes here.')
```

...is all you need. Just paste there. If you want it to look the same on larger consoles, you may need to force new lines. Here's a similar question that handles new lines in console log:

[how to create line breaks in console.log() in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660349/how-to-create-line-breaks-in-console-log-in-node)