# Add extra new line in the output using CSS, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I am creating a blog website. I am taking the input using a `textarea` and storing it in MongoDB. For displaying the data I use: `white-space: pre-wrap;`.

With pre-wrap if I give the input as:

```
hello
world
```

The output is:

```
hello
world
```

I want the output as:

```
hello

world
```

Code:
Taking the input:

```
<form action="/post/compose" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="postTitle">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="postTitle" >
      <label for="postBody">Body</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="postBody" rows="10" col="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Publish</button>
</form>
```

Storing the input in database:

```
 const post=new Post({
      Title:req.body.postTitle,
      Content:req.body.postBody,
    
      });
      post.save();
```

Displaying the input

```
<div id="fullpost">
<h2 class="text-dark"><%= post.Title %></h2>
<p  class="text-dark" id="Postcontent"><%- post.Content %></p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#Postcontent{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Now as I added white-space property if there is \n in the input ,in the output single whitespace is included.But I want two white spaces.
Is it possible to do this without regex in Javascript? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660349/how-to-create-line-breaks-in-console-log-in-node/49660376

Comment: Well how can I add \n to user input?

Comment: A little context woudl help. You should post your code

Comment: @FlorentArlandis Hey!Thank you for replying.I added some code.

Comment: Do you want a new blank line after each entry, or do you want the text to display a 100% lineheight gap between each line of text displayed?

Comment: @Hugh I want to add a new blank line when the user press enter while posting the content

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it sounds like what you want is to display line breaks entered in the original text?

In that case, probably you don't want a `<textarea>`. You might like to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247702/using-html5-how-do-i-use-contenteditable-fields-in-a-form-submission) by replacing your `textarea` with an element (say, a `div`) with [`contenteditable=true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable), and then using a JavaScript function to capture the contents of the div (you won't be able to get it with a standard form submission).

Comment: do we have any easier solution?

Comment: Not if you want to use `<textarea>`. The problem is you won't be able to tell the difference between a space and a line break when the form payload hits your server.