# why there is no line ends in console logging a html

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

pls write this in `#cedit`

```
lorem
ipsum
dolor
```

console will be:

```
lorem<div>ipsum</div><div>dolor</div>
```

how to get line ends in console like this:

```
lorem
<div>ipsum</div>
<div>dolor</div>
```

so I have one single object - `html` and not multiple objects to insert a '\n' between them

```js
$('#cedit').on('input', function(){
let a = $(this).html();
console.log(a);
});
```

```css
#cedit{
background:gold;
min-height:99px;
padding:9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cedit' contenteditable></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to create line breaks in console.log() in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660349/how-to-create-line-breaks-in-console-log-in-node)

Comment: unfortunatelly no - I have one single object - `html` and not multiple objects to insert a `\n` between them

Comment: Why? Because contenteditable won't insert `\n` since it's not needed in html. What is the problem with not having text line breaks?

Comment: @charlietfl - problem - I need to control ceditable behaviour in different scenarios - and it is very tedious if everything is in one block, without breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it:

```js
$('#cedit').on('input', function(){
let a = $(this).html();
console.log(a.replaceAll("<div","\n<div"));
});
```

```css
#cedit{
background:gold;
min-height:99px;
padding:9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cedit' contenteditable></div>
```